# Angular manifest.json Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, html, angular, manifest.json

Angular 7 project, I used https://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate my favicon.
It came with a manifest file which always throws an error when I do a prod build.

The manifest file is pretty simple

```
{
  "name": "My app",
  "short_name": "app",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

With a link to it in the index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="assets/images/manifest.json" />
```

Note I have all my images and this manifest file in `/assets/images`

And in the angular.json I have

```
"assets": ["src/assets", "src/assets/images"],
```

My best lead right now is in my prod build, the manifest.json file is showing as empty here. I'm not sure why though. When I do a local prod build I see the manifest file in the correct location with the full json.
[image]

It it keeps spitting out
`Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.`
In the console. Mostly likely due to the above. So if I can find a reason it's showing as empty, it'll probably solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using service worker?

Comment: Nope, not sure what that is (I googled it and found an angular page on it), but prior to this message I hadn't. Just wanted to get the error messages out of the console for the most part.

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache of the page?

Comment: Yes I have, I also having caching turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file should be `manifest.webmanifest`. File should have `.webmanifest` extension.

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Comment: I don't think that should make a different, their page says it works with .json also (using chrome here)